# Массив объектов jQuery в селекторе jQuery

Tags: jquery, массивы, javascript

Скажем есть две переменные

```
var toYesterday = $("#ToYesterday");
var toADay = $("#ToADay");
```

И теперь я хочу "взять" их селектором Jquery.
Например так:

```
$([toYesterday, toADay]);
```

Но это не правильный способ. Как быть?

Comment: `var both=toYesterday.add(toADay);`

Comment: Про этот способ в курсе, я его описал в комментарии к ответу Pavel Volyntsev.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В JQuery можно передать массив DOM элементов:

```
var toYesterday = $("#ToYesterday")[0],
    toADay = $("#ToADay")[0];

$([toYesterday, toADay])
```

или как вариант:

```
var toYesterday = $("#ToYesterday"),
    toADay = $("#ToADay");

$([toYesterday[0], toADay[0]])
```

Comment: То что надо! Подскажите для понимания, используя конструкцию [0] мы таким образом разворачиваем объект JQuery в объект JavaScript? Или иными словами избавляемся от объектной обёртки JQuery?

Comment: Отвечаю на свой вопрос - да. Это эквивалент $(this).get(0).

Answer (score 3):

Комбинация селекторов

```
$("#ToYesterday, #ToADay");
```

Comment: Это понятно, но я хочу использовать именно переменные, то есть кэш селекторов, а не снова их. Но похоже такого селектора сразу с несколькими объектами JQuery просто не существует. Единственное, что остаётся это $(toYesterday).add(toADay)